# Backward compaitablity of type hinted python 3 code

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, type-hinting

Is there any way to make python 3 code containing [type hinting annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) to work with python 2 also?

```
def get(axyz: list, window_size: int=WINDOW_SIZE) -> numpy.array:
    return numpy.array(axyz)
```

More importantly is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The type annotating syntax is not valid in python2. [pep484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files) mentions stub files for compatibility with python2.